# what is the purpose of pre-processor macros defined in files linux/compiler.h?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, macros, gcc-warning

I am very new to Linux kernel. And I am using the sparse tool to clean the noise present in the code. I encountered these macros:

```
   # define __user      __attribute__((noderef, address_space(1)))
   # define __kernel    __attribute__((address_space(0)))
   # define __safe      __attribute__((safe))
   # define __force __attribute__((force))
   # define __nocast    __attribute__((nocast)) 
   # define __iomem __attribute__((noderef, address_space(2)))
   # define __must_hold(x)  __attribute__((context(x,1,1)))
   # define __acquires(x)   __attribute__((context(x,0,1)))
   # define __releases(x)   __attribute__((context(x,1,0)))
   # define __acquire(x)    __context__(x,1)
   # define __release(x)    __context__(x,-1)
   # define __cond_lock(x,c)    ((c) ? ({ __acquire(x); 1; }) : 0)
   # define __percpu    __attribute__((noderef, address_space(3)))
```

And now I want to know: how they are used by sparse to report the errors/warning?

My questions:

1. I want the details how they help compiler and sparse to report the warnings.
2. What are these **address_space(x)** **context(X, x, x)** and there purpose ?
3. What is the purpose of **__nocast**, **__force**, **__user**, **__safe** ?

Answer (score 5):

I think all these macros only have meaning in the context of [sparse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse) (manpages [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sparse) - You can find the descriptions of all these attributes and sparse warnings there). If you take a look above in the source file you copied there is a big `__CHECKER__` macro used to enable them.

I'm not sure if gcc does anything with them at this point - I think it kind of silently ignores them ... In one of his e-mails back in 2004 Linus Torvalds was saying that:

> This is important to remember: for gcc, the sparse annotations are
>   meaningless. They can still be useful just to tell the *programmer* 
>   that "hey, that pointer you got wasn't a normal pointer" in a fairly 
>   readable manner, but in the end, unless you use sparse, they don't 
>   actually *do* anything.

There are some tickets opened for this purpose - http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-sparse/msg03366.html .

Comment: Thanks for sharing the articles. But I am still not able to find the answer how it helps sparse to report these problem. I am still not getting how`address_space(num)` is actually helping to resolve and report the warning. Similarly `context(x,x,x)`.